# Strange behavior with PSEXEC running command prompt on external pc

Tags: windows, command-line, psexec

I discovered this quite by accident, but have since been able to replicate it at will, and I wonder if anyone has any explanation.  I also wonder if it might point to a security hole in one of the involved programs.

What happens is that if I run psexec.exe on another computer in my network, and I am running the command prompt, the following happens:

> If I type (for example) H: to go to my H Drive, and then I simultaneously press the 'Enter' key and the '\' key, the next two lines look like this:

```
\
H:\>
```

That in itself is not so weird; however, on the second line, which is now where the cursor is residing, if I hit the back space, I am able to delete the first character of the prompt, and only the first character, so it looks like this:

> H:\

Then if I hit enter again, it goes back to normal.  All that is weird, but I can make up an explanation maybe involving the escaping of a character and a delay with psexec.  However, if I try the first experiment without putting the drive letter and colon, and from a blank command prompt hit 'Enter' and '\' simultaneously twice instead of just once, I see:

> \'P' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

And then if I just hit 'Enter', I see:

> 'P' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

(Notice the abscence of the '\' the second time through).  After that it is back to normal.

In addition, If I type >\>, I see the following:

> H:>>\>
>
> H:\>

Pretty weird, but it seems too perfect to just be a fluke.  Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I speculate what you are seeing is likely due in part to the network latency between yourself and the remote system combined with how the display buffer works in psexec.

Comment: I suspect that too.  But that doesn't add to my understanding.